# Reading urls from a text file instead of listing one url inside the function?

Tags: python, multithreading, text, python-requests, readline

How can i read multiple urls from a text file instead of listing one url in this script?

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests

from timer import timer

URL = 'www.url1.com'


def fetch(session, url):
    with session.get(url) as response:
        print(response.text)


@timer(1, 5)
def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            executor.map(fetch, [session] * 100, [URL] * 100)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Comment: Just read the file and get the urls. Whats the problem?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the urls in a list then use map to send the session and each url to the function:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
#from timer import timer


#########  create test file

URLsTest = '''
https://www.yahoo.com
https://www.oracle.com
https://www.python.org
https://www.reuters.com
https://www.walmart.com
https://www.google.com
'''.strip()

with open('tmp.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(URLsTest)
    
####################


#URL = 'https://www.url1.com'

with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls=f.read().split('\n')    # url list

def fetch(tt):  # received tuple
    session, url = tt
    print('Processing', url)
    with session.get(url) as response:
        print(url, str(len(response.text)))

#@timer(1, 5)
def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:  # for now, just one session
            results = executor.map(fetch, [(session, u) for u in urls])  # tuple list (session, url), each tuple passed to function
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
    # write all results to text file
    with open('allresults.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f2:
        s = ""
        for r in results:  # tuple (url, html)
            s += r[0] + '\n' + r[1] + '\n\n'
        f2.write(s)
            
main()
```

Output

```
Processing https://www.yahoo.com
Processing https://www.oracle.com
Processing https://www.python.org
Processing https://www.reuters.com
Processing https://www.walmart.com
Processing https://www.google.com
https://www.python.org 48984
https://www.yahoo.com 418732
https://www.oracle.com 36374
https://www.google.com 12904
https://www.reuters.com 195139
https://www.walmart.com 250661
```

Comment: I will look into this now and see if it works as a solution. How can i save the response into one text file?